# Error de permiso al abrir archivo DBF Integration Service SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssis, ssms

Buen dia comunidad, primer posteo para mi y espero logren ayudarme.

estoy ejecutando un workflow mediante SSIS de Visual Studio el cual es un insert y update de un DBF (Archivo alojado en el servidor interno de la empresa) hacia una tabla de SQL SERVER y se ejecuta perfecto en VS, lo despliego hacia Integration Service Catalogs en SQL SERVER (tambien alojado en el servidor interno de la empresa) y al ejecutar el paquete en SSMS me aparece un error el cual es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tema permisos solo controle que el usuario que ejecuta la tarea o bien esta configurado en el archivo DTXS, tenga suficientes privilegios sobre la carpeta de destino, tambien que tenga acceso a la base de datos, aun asi sigo con el mismo problema, lo unico que logre es que funcione desde el propio servidor donde se aloja el SQL SERVER, ahi dentro ejecuto la tarea y la realiza sin errores, pero si lo hago desde otro equipo remotamente, en la misma red, con el mismo usuario de dominio, utilizando el SSMS de misma version, la tarea falla y arroja ese error.

Que me puede estar faltando? o que puede estar fallando a nivel permisos?

Saludos y Gracias